# (void) volatile variable optimization

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-optimization, volatile

I am embedded fw engineer. Sometimes we need to make dummy reads of some registers from different serial interfaces. I can do it in several ways:

1. using dummy variable:

```
...
volatile uint8_t dummy = SI->REG;
...
```

2. using (void):

```
...
(void) SI->REG;
...
```

REG field of SI structure is declared as volatile too.
I'm pretty sure, that compiler will not remove dummy read in first case, but can I be sure, that it will not remove it in second one? IMHO it looks much prettier in the code and also doesn't produce 'unused variable' warning.

Comment: If `SI->REG` is `volatile`-qualified, then the C standard requires a C implementation to actually access it when program execution reaches `(void) SI->REG;`. What constitutes “access” is defined by the C implementation.

Comment: `uint8_t dummy` doesn't need to be `volatile` if your `REG` field is correctly declared as `volatile`.  Assigning to a `volatile` local variable would force the compiler to store the load result to the stack, as well as actually doing the load.  The second way might depend on your compiler whether it counts as a "volatile access", but GCC / clang do count it so they do actually load.